# Accordian in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to add accordian in my angularjs app. I have to show some details on button click "Additional Information". Not sure how to toggle class panel with button click.

Here is my html:

```
<button ng-click="showPanel()" class="accordian">Additional Information</button>

    <br>

    <div class="panel"  style="width: 750px;">
        <div class="panel-heading">Attributes</div>
            <table class="table table-bordered">                    
                <tbody>
                    <tr >
                        <td>{{room.allowFecc}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
button.accordian {
background-color: #eee;
color: #444;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px;
width: 100%;
border: none;
text-align: left;
outline: none;
font-size: 15px;
transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
padding: 0 18px;
display: none;
background-color: white;
}

div.panel.show {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: `ngClass` on a variable that tells whether the accordian is showing or not. Whats your `showPanel` function look like?

Comment: $scope.showPanel = function(){
           this.classList.toggle("active");
           this.nextElementSibloing.classList.toggle("show");
        }

I need to change this to angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drop the class that simply does a `display: block` - Angular has built in directives like `ngShow` and `ngHide` which will take care of this for you. Basically in Angular, you want to manipulate the data, and then let the view bind back to the data.

For your basic example above, you want to toggle a variable from `true` to `false` to show the accordian or hide it, and then based on the variable, add a class:

The Angular:

```
$scope.toggleAccordian = function() {
    $scope.showAccordian = !$scope.showAccordian; //our toggle variable
}
```

The HTML:

```
<button ng-click="toggleAccordian()" class="accordian">Additional Information</button>

<br>

<div class="panel" ng-show="showAccordian" ng-class="{'accordianActiveClass': showAccordian }" style="width: 750px;">
    <div class="panel-heading">Attributes</div>
        <table class="table table-bordered">                    
            <tbody>
                <tr >
                    <td>{{room.allowFecc}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

The `ng-class="{'accordianActiveClass': showAccordian }"` is the class magic, replace `accordianActiveClass` with the class you want to show, and when the condition is satisfied (`showAccordian`) the class will be added.